# get part of the file name from each file in a list in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am uploading files in a list into S3 using `uploadFileList()`
So this API takes list (records) as parameter like below

```
MultipleFileUpload xfer = tm.uploadFileList(bucketName, "TEST",new File(fileLocation), records);
```

The records in a list like this

```
21564_114762642_ANA_9ECB7C98-C2D7-428A-B6AD-7A6C62E1A7BE_App.xml.gz
21224_114762642_ANA_9ECB7C98-C2D7-428A-B6AD-7A6C62E1A7BE_App.xml.gz
20780_114762642_ANA_9ECB7C98-C2D7-428A-B6AD-7A6C62E1A7BE_App.xml.gz
20407_114762642_ANA_9ECB7C98-C2D7-428A-B6AD-7A6C62E1A7BE_App.xml.gz
```

This is working fine as of now .
Now i need to add prefix in the API as the first four digit of the file name like `21564` will be the prefix for the first file 
So to do this i have to iterate over the list and add file by file but that will slow down the upload into S3 compare to uploading list .

Is there anyway to add prefix while uploading list into S3 and the files in the list are random but pattern is fix ?

Answer (score 0):

See the S3 documentation about [object keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html). Because S3 buckets are flat (not a filesystem hierarchy), you can tell Amazon the key prefix to use for your uploaded files, thus grouping them all under the same prefix. For example, I could supply "MovieReviews/" as a prefix for a list of files and the resulting object keys in S3 would begin with that. Some tools understand the slashes and allow you to browse your S3 bucket as a directory hierarchy.

In your case, if the files should use the first N characters as a grouping key, then you can upload them in batches by first grouping according to that substring, e.g. `fileList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, N)))`

Comment: Sorry i did not get the solution ..So in my case what should be at the place of TEST as key name

Comment: The key name is something you choose so that you can group the files into a hierarchy. If you don't care about that, you could try using an empty String. Null might also work.

Comment: Josh i think you did not get my question ..My problem is i am not able to get First five digit of the file name on the fly ..